TV Cartoon Animation: A strange character promised to get rid of crows on a farmer’s corn farm
This is a cartoon animation that I watched on TV in the late 1980’s. 
A farmer (a bear?) wanted to stop some crows from eating up the corn on his farm. A scarecrow-like pest controller visited the farmer and promised the farmer he would get rid of the crows. 
Thereafter, the pest controller used an array of gadgets to attempt to stop the crows. The most dramatic tool he employed was a rag doll, which he set down on the field. In rhythmic motions, the rag doll danced off to the “Dum, Dum! Dum, Dum! DUM! DUM!” beats of drums.
The crows, enthralled by the rhythm, all lined up behind the rag doll and danced away a la the Pied Piper. Incidentally, the farmer was so delighted by the drum rhythms that he lined up behind the last crow and would have danced off too had the pest controller not stopped him.
In the end, the pest controller is revealed as three (I think) crows in disguise. Having hoodwinked the farmer, they and their fellow crows settled down to make a meal of the farmer’s farm.

Sounds like the Barney Bear cartoon Cobs and Robbers, but it's quite old (1953).

Barney is plagued by crows. Joe Scarecrow comes along and, using a wind-up puppet, gets the crows to follow it out in a conga line. He then tells Barney everything is under control only to remove his scarecrow costume when Barney leaves, revealing two more crows. The crows get the best of Barney, eventually turning his field into popped corn.

The short is currently available online. Here's a frame:


SOLVED! Muchos gracias! It is indeed it!

@FelleyMoore Glad to hear! But don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it). This effectively marks the question as 'solved'.
